# MockSchemaRegistryClient not registering avro schema: Cannot get schema from schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am writing a spring boot Integration test using spring-kafka-test 2.6.3 `EmbeddedKafka` and Junit 5 for a topology that consumes avro messages. In the test I am using `MockSchemaReigstryClient`

I am registering the mock schema client and configuring the subjects as suggested in this [PR](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues/1155) that's now closed. But I am getting and receiving the following error:

```
    Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro unknown schema for id 1
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot get schema from schema registry!
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.MockSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaBySubjectAndIdFromRegistry(MockSchemaRegistryClient.java:176) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-6.0.1.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.MockSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaBySubjectAndId(MockSchemaRegistryClient.java:232) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-6.0.1.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.MockSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaById(MockSchemaRegistryClient.java:215) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-6.0.1.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.schemaFromRegistry(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:279) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-6.0.1.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:98) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-6.0.1.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:77) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-6.0.1.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:55) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-6.0.1.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroDeserializer.deserialize(SpecificAvroDeserializer.java:66) ~[kafka-streams-avro-serde-6.0.1.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroDeserializer.deserialize(SpecificAvroDeserializer.java:38) ~[kafka-streams-avro-serde-6.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:60) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.deserializeValue(SourceNode.java:55) ~[kafka-streams-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer.deserialize(RecordDeserializer.java:66) ~[kafka-streams-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.updateHead(RecordQueue.java:176) ~[kafka-streams-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:112) ~[kafka-streams-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:185) ~[kafka-streams-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:865) ~[kafka-streams-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.addRecordsToTasks(TaskManager.java:938) ~[kafka-streams-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:640) ~[kafka-streams-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:551) ~[kafka-streams-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:510) ~[kafka-streams-2.6.0.jar:na]
```

The production code works fine. So, it seems like I am missing something in the test setup. Any pointers will be appreciated. Here's the [gist](https://gist.github.com/surysharma/3e2c312b709ae39cba0f2535058c81bb) of code.

**Update**: I am using kafka-schema-registry-client-6.0.1 maven dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Your StreamsConfig still uses a default `SpecificAvroSerde` which (yes) uses a `MockSchemRegistryClient` since you configure the `schemaRegistryUrl : mock://` but it does not have the schemas needed for serde. This `MockSchemRegistryClient` is a different instance than the one you configured for your producer and consumer in your test.

```
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde.class.getName());
```

Consider this flow: (1) Test Produder --> (2) IN_TOPIC -> (3) StreamApp -> (4) OUT_TOPIC -> (5) Test Consumer.

You have configured `MockSchemaRegistryClient` for Producer at (1), and consumer at (5) and even registered required schemas, but not yet for the one (main app) at (3). Hence the error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot get schema from schema registry!
```

One way to solve this is to use a `MockSpecificAvroSerde` that points to a registry that has the schemas in test:

`application.yaml`:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            configuration:
              specific.avro.reader: true
              default:
                value.serde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
```

But for `application-test.yaml`:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            configuration:
              schema.registry.url: mock://localtest
              specific.avro.reader: true
              default:
                value.serde: your.custom.serde.that.uses.a.mock.schema.regiter.client.bydefault.MockSpecificAvroSerde
```

Comment: Hey, if we are not using cloud Kafka what property would we need to change in test.yaml?

Comment: Should be `spring.kafka.streams.properties.schema.registry.url`